# Android SDK and Eclipse: strings.xml graphical view not updating

Tags: android, eclipse

I installed the newest version of the Android SDK bundle not too long ago, been working fine but one thing that has been a minor annoyance to me is that when adding to strings.xml file when I try to use the graphical interface they give it is very difficult to get it to update.  Saving, opening, closing usually doesn't work.

Sometimes if I resort or change selection criteria it will update partially but even then it's hard to get it to display my changes properly.  I've taken to simply manually editing the XML file rather than using their provided GUI for it, but I do sometimes wonder if it's not some simple thing I could do to fix this.

I guess it might be hard for you guys to know what is specifically causing the issue on my end but maybe someone has encountered a similar problem before and knows some things that might have caused it?

Well, if not I can continue editing the XML file manually as I've been doing, not as if it's all that much trouble but I thought I might as well ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue and is posted [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57689). I suppose its only logical to edit string resource directly in xml until the issue is fixed. My Adt version and relevant information:

Android Developer Tools Build: v22.6.2-1085508 Blockquote

Comment: Thanks, looks pretty similar to the problem I was having.  I guess I'll just continue manually editing the xml then.